# Error in uploading csv using fgetcsv

Tags: php, csv

I'm inserting products from a csv file into a database using the following code:

```
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");
    if ($handle !== FALSE) 
        {
    while (!feof($handle))
         {
            $data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'");
            if($data[0]) {
    $NewOurPrc=$data[7]*$data[8];
    $qry="INSERT INTO tbl_product VALUES
                    (
                        '',
                        '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[6])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[7])."',
                        '".addslashes($NewOurPrc)."',
                        '".addslashes($data[9])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[10])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[11])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[12])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[13])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[14])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[15])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[16])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[17])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[18])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[19])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[20])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[21])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[22])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[23])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[24])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[25])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[26])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[27])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[28])."',        
                        '".addslashes($data[29])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[30])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[31])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[32])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[33])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[34])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[35])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[36])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[37])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[38])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[39])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[40])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[41])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[42])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[43])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[44])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[45])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[46])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[47])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[48])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[49])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[50])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[51])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[52])."',
                        '".addslashes($data[53])."'     
                    )
                ";
             if(($data[0]!='id')&&($data[0]!='')) { $updateResult=mysql_query($qry)or die (mysql_error()); }
             ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',true);
           }

        }
        fclose($handle);
}
```

When query executes most of the rows uploads properly. But some fields are not uploaded properly. ie the cells positions are mismatching. My csv contains more than 200 rows and 54 cells. 
Thank you

[image]

Comment: And what'syour question now?

Comment: inspect your raw data - compare rows that are incorrectly imported to rows that are correctly imported. Do the incorrect rows contain any unexpected delimiters or field separators? Any control characters? Anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: and my problem is values from csv cells are not inserted into its particular field in sql database. @TiMESPLiNTER

Comment: Which values, how does the data structure of the CSV looks like? We need more information to help you.

Comment: please provide doc.csv link to make question more clear